# ISTIO authorization policy support for a wild card rule

Tags: istio

I was trying trying to implement an ISTIO authorization policy where I have a requirement to allow a request if a value in claim matches in any part of particular string.

Example: The Rule looks something like this:

```
rules:
  - to:
    - operation:
        methods: ["GET"]
        hosts: ["sample.com"]
    when:
    - key: request.auth.claims[TEST_STRING]
      values: ["SUBSTR" , "*SUBSTR" , "*SUBSTR*" , "SUBSTR*"]
```

Everything works fine if the value 'SUBSTR' contains as a prefix or suffix in claims, But if the string SUBSTR is in a middle the claim  the condition failing.
Is there any solution where the request is allowed if the values contains a substr in the middle.In my case  when
the claim contains string xyxSUBSTRpqr  is failing to match the rule.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no such template for condition with both prefix and suffix that You are trying to use.

According to istio [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/authorization-policy/#Rule):

> ### Rule
>
> Rule matches requests from a list of sources that perform a list of
> operations subject to a list of conditions. A match occurs when at
> least one source, operation and condition matches the request. An
> empty rule is always matched.
>
> Any string field in the rule supports Exact, Prefix, Suffix and
> Presence match:
>
> - Exact match: “abc” will match on value “abc”.
> - Prefix match: “abc*” will match on value “abc” and “abcd”.
> - Suffix match: “*abc” will match on value “abc” and “xabc”.
> - Presence match: “*” will match when value is not empty.